# Source Generators: How can I prevent the instantiation of a base class declared as "partial" in C#?

Tags: c#, abstract-class, partial-classes, sourcegenerators

## Summary

I have a base class which inherits from an abstract class, but must itself be declared as `partial`, because I'm using *Source Generators* to generate parts of the implementation.

How can I prevent the instantiation of that `partial class` in C#? Is there some way to do this at **compile-time**?

**Edit:** I'm using C# 8.0 (.NET Standard 2.1) with a Xamarin.Forms project.

I've tried `partial abstract`, but that isn't allowed.

## TL;DR

In one of my projects, I have been using an `abstract class` that serves as a base class for *ViewModels* to implement the *MVVM patter*n. Previously, said base class implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, but now I am switching to the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) in order to be able to use the [MVVM Source Generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/overview) *(which I have used in other projects extensively already, I even wrote a [blog series](https://ewerspej.hashnode.dev/series/mvvm-goodness) about them)*.

Apparently, in C#, a class can only be either `partial` or `abstract` but not both at the same time, which makes sense. Since the *Source Generators* work with `partial` classes only, my base class cannot be `abstract` anymore. However, this creates the problem that I cannot prevent the base class from being instantiated at compile-time. While it was still an `abstract class`, it couldn't be instantiated, but now it's possible to do so.

### Abstract base class

This is what the base class used to look like *(reduced/modified example)*:

```cs
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _myBool;
    public bool MyBool
    {
        get => _myBool;
        set => SetField(ref _myBool, value);
    }

    private ICommand _myCommand;
    public ICommand MyCommand => _myCommand ??= new Command(MyMethod);

    private void MyMethod()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

### Partial base class

The changed base class looks like this now:

```cs
public partial class ViewModelBase : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _myBool;

    [RelayCommand]
    private void MyMethod()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It's much smaller, as expected, but now it can be instantiated, which is something I would like to prevent.

Comment: Make it abstract -  `public abstract partial class ViewModelBase ...`.  You can have partial abstract classes.

Comment: @GuruStron In which C# version?

Comment: In any which is more or less relevant nowadays, AFAIK.

Comment: oh, okay, I missed that. I tried `partial abstract`, but it didn't allow it. It seems that `abstract partial` works, however. I guess that answers it, then. Thanks

Comment: If you give the class a single constructor and make it protected, it cannot be directly instantiated (except by subclass instances), but sub-class instances can be instantiated.

Comment: @Flydog57 That's also a very good point.

Comment: Actually, you can have multiple constructors, as long as all of them are protected (or even more _actually_ as long as they are all protected or private and at least one is protected).  But, you get the idea - no public constructors.

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes, I'm familiar with the concept of protected constructors, but I didn't think of it 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare partial classes as abstract, but note that order of keywords is important (otherwise it will not compile):

```cs
public abstract partial class ViewModelBase : ObservableObject
{
    // ...
}
```

As per [spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#1421-general) - modifiers like `abstract`, `sealed`, etc should precede the `partial` keyword.